# how to handle table row's input field value which is dynamicaly created using jq in django views.py and print data another page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

when click add row button it add new row with two input field but name is different

here is my view

```
#views.py
def index(request):
#if post request came 
if request.method == 'POST':
for i in range(len(request.POST.getlist())):
        dd = list(request.POST.getlist('name['+i+']'))
    ff = list(request.POST.getlist('email['+i+']'))
    context = {
        'dataone': dd,
        'datatwo': ff,

    }

    #getting our showdata template
    template = loader.get_template('loggedin.html')

    #returing the template 
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
else:
    #if post request is not true 
    #returing the form template 
    template = loader.get_template('dynamictabel.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

how to get all values of input field in one variable and send to the other page

Answer (score 0):

Here is my main form when click add row button it add new row with two input field but name is different increase with name=name[+1]

```
#mymainform.html
<table id="tab_logic" name="mytable">
            <thead>
                <tr >

                    <th class="text-center">
                        data1
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        data2
                    </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                        delete
                    </th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id='addr0'>
                    <td>
    <input type="text" name="name[0]"  class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
    <input type="text" name="email[0]"  class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
<td><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm delete">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td>

                </tr>
                <tr id='addr1'>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="name[1]"  class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name="email[1]"  class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
<td><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm delete"><span 
class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td>
</tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```